# properties file to vo using only 1-bean

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot.
boot configuration contains in application.yml

this is my situation.

interface CommonService

class AServiceImpl.java + a-config.properties
class BServiceImpl.java + b-config.properties
...

```
@PropertiesSource(value="${b.config.file.name})
@Service("bService")
public class BServiceImpl implements CommonService{
     ...
}
```

properties files are contains same property, difference values.

i want properties using in just own service.
and not getter type(not getProperty).

can i?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use only one property then @Autowired Environment and you can use this.getClass().getSimpleName() for dynamic prefix property name

application.yml

```
BServiceImpl : yourchild : yourvalue
```

AService

```
@Service("aService")
public class AServiceImpl implements CommonService{
     @Autowired
     Environment env;

}
```

BService

```
@Service("bService")
public class BServiceImpl implements CommonService{
     @Autowired
     Environment env;

}
```

How to a getProperty

```
env.getProperty(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+"yourchild");
```